# Can't hide div in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When clicking module class it shows emptylabel. but i cant hide the module class.

```
<div id="b" class="tab-pane fade in active" >
        <div class="secondrow">
            <div ng-show="divshow">
                <label class="emptylabel"> <input type="button" value="back"  class="backbutton" ng-click="hidediv()"></label>

            </div>


            <div class="module">
                <a href="#/b" class="{{module}}" ng-click="showdiv()">
                    <div class="col-sm-4"><label>Jawaharlal Nehru</label></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1"><label>111111</label></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2"><label>2222222</label></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3"><label>3333333</label></div>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.showdiv = function () {
    $scope.divshow = true;
    $scope.module = false;
  }
 // Hide Div
 $scope.hidediv = function () {
   $scope.divshow = false;
 }
}]);
```

Comment: Please explain what you try to do, at least for me it is not clear. What is `showdiv()`? is that predefined or do you have to code it?

Comment: <div id="redeem" class="tab-pane fade in active" ><div class="secondrow"><div ng-show="divshow">
<label class="emptylabel"> <input type="button" value="back"  class="backbutton" ng-click="hidediv()"></label> </div>
<div class="module">
 <a href="#/redeem" class="{{module}}" ng-click="showdiv()">
 <div class="col-sm-4"><label>Jawaharlal Nehru</label></div>
 <div class="col-sm-1"><label>12,000</label></div>
 <div class="col-sm-2"><label>5.7grams</label></div>
 <div class="col-sm-3"><label>11-01-2016</label></div>
                    </a>
                </div>this is my html page

Comment: my app.js file:       app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.showdiv = function () {
        $scope.divshow = true;
        $scope.module  = false;
    }
// Hide Div
    $scope.hidediv = function () {
        $scope.divshow = false;
    }

}]);

Comment: Please add this to your question instead of the comments, like this it's impossible to read!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. If you want to toggle between the `emptylabel` and `module`, the you can use `ng-show` for both of them, based on the `divshow` variable:

```
<div ng-show="divshow">
  <label class="emptylabel">
    <input type="button" value="back" class="backbutton" ng-click="hidediv()">
  </label>
</div>

<div class="module" ng-show="!divshow">
  <a href="#/b" class="{{module}}" ng-click="showdiv()">
    ...
  </a>
</div>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.showdiv = function () {
    $scope.divshow = true;
  }
 $scope.hidediv = function () {
   $scope.divshow = false;
 }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your ng-controller declaration in the HTML look like? For example mine usually look something like this, with the capture variable 'vm':

```
<div data-ng-controller="FooController as vm">
  <div>
    <span data-ng-click="vm.showDiv()"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Inside your controller:

```
function FooController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.showDiv = showDiv;

  function showdiv() {
    // Your code here
  }
}
```